# How to animate the progress of a LinearProgressIndicator in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `LinearProgressIndicator` that correctly shows the current progress. Now I would like the progress to be animated and I thought this would be super simple with `animateFloatAsState`. Well, not sure what I am not grokking, but with the code below, the progress is not animated, but immediately shown at the correct place.

```
@Composable
fun MyIndicator() {
    val progressAnimDuration = 1500
    val progressAnimation by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = 0.35f
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = progressAnimDuration, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing)
    )
     LinearProgressIndicator(
        progress = progressAnimation,
        ...
        modifier = Modifier           
           .fillMaxWidth()
           .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)). // Rounded edges
    )
}
```

So whenever I show that component on the screen, I would expect the progress to be animated to its correct progress state. But instead, the progress is not animated but immediately shown at the correct progress state.

What's wrong here? :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had a similar problem, in my case I used LaunchedEffect to update the progress from zero to the desired value

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AnimatedLinearProgressIndicator(
    indicatorProgress: Float,
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current,
) {
    var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(0F) }
    val progressAnimDuration = 1_500
    val progressAnimation by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = progress,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = progressAnimDuration, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing),
    )
    LinearProgressIndicator(
        progress = { progressAnimation },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
    )
    LaunchedEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        progress = indicatorProgress
    }
}
```

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer, as it more closely answers my question of starting the animation as soon as the component becomes visible. 

I ended up going with the same approach in the end (see my comments below).

Comment: I achieved the same result without the `LaunchedEffect` and `progress` variable.

Comment: Doesnt work for me. it is in final state immediately. Dont know what I'm missing...

Comment: Doesn't work for me as well, just showing the final state immediately.

Comment: In the targetValue of the progressAnimation I use the progress variable instead of indicatorProgress and now it work for me :D

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it. I use progress indicator to simulate a loading effect, then jump to the login activity.

```
var currentProgress by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
val context = LocalContext.current

// jump to Login Activity after animation
val currentPercentage by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = currentProgress,
    animationSpec =  tween( durationMillis = 1000, easing = LinearEasing),
    label = "progress",
    finishedListener = { _ -> context.startActivity(Intent(context, LoginActivity3::class.java)) }
)

LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
    currentProgress = 1f
}

Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),contentAlignment = Alignment.Center)
{
    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
    {
        LinearProgressIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier.width(220.dp).height(5.dp),
            progress = currentPercentage,
            color = colorResource(R.color.green_500)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Composable
    fun MyIndicator(indicatorProgress: Float) {
        var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        val progressAnimDuration = 1500
        val progressAnimation by animateFloatAsState(
            targetValue = progress,
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = progressAnimDuration, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing)
        )
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.White)
                .fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            LinearProgressIndicator(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)),
                progress = progressAnimation
            )
        }
        LaunchedEffect(indicatorProgress) {
            progress = indicatorProgress
        }
    }
```

A small modification made in the answer by @Dani Chucks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very important parameter `visibilityThreshold` in the `animateFloatAsState`, you have to set it to `0.001f` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was worked -

```
 var animationPlayed by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }
        val currentPercentage = animateFloatAsState(targetValue =
            if(animationPlayed) percentage else 0f,
            animationSpec = tween( durationMillis = 4000)
        )
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = true){
            animationPlayed=true
        }
    
    LinearProgressIndicator(...progress = currentPercentage)
```

Answer (score 0):

You case use the Animatable, but you need the LaunchEffect to trigger the animation

```
  val percent = remember { Animatable(0f) }


  LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
        percent.animateTo(
            targetValue = yourPercentage ,
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = (1000 * (1f - percent.value)).toInt(),
                easing = FastOutLinearInEasing
            )
        )
    })

     LinearProgressIndicator(
            progress = percent.value
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by having a mutable state at 0 then make it null at the end of the code to trigger recomposition

```
{
var starterProgressValue by remember { mutableStateOf<Float?>(0f) }
val actualProgress = 1f

AnimatedProgressBar(
    progress = starterProgressValue ?: actualProgress,
    duration = 3000,
    modifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
        .height(12.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
)

starterProgressValue = null
```

}